# mobile menu collapse not working with scrollspy

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi when I enable mobile menu collapsing it stops scrollspy from working.

They both work fine individually but not together, is this a limitation of bootstrap?

This is my navbar code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="80">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Davies Builders Stoke Ltd</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#partners">Partners</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

The divs below have the correct ids, removing: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"` from each of `#navigations a` causes scrollspy to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limitation of bootstrap is not being able to use the collapsing `.navbar` with `scrollspy`, the following code works around that.

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
    if  (window.innerWidth < 768){
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Great, except it, doesn't work for a dropdown item.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by moving `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"` to the li element.

Like:

`<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
   <a href="#about">About</a>
</li>`